# Can any one suggest me how to get my friends list Profile picture and status

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xmpp, xmppframework

Currently i am working chat based application.I am successfully upload my profile picture. Can any one suggest me how to get my friends list, Profile picture and status. I tried below code.I am using `XMPP` Framework for Chat.

**This code for retriving my own Prifile picture**

```
    xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
xmppvCardTempModule= [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];

XMPPvCardAvatarModule *xmppvCardAvatarModule = [[XMPPvCardAvatarModule alloc] initWithvCardTempModule:xmppvCardTempModule];

XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@localhost",str]];
NSData *avtarData = [xmppvCardAvatarModule photoDataForJID:jid];

  **This code for Upload my own Prifile picture**

 NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];

[newvCardTemp setGivenName:@"gireesh"];
[newvCardTemp setSortString:@"Chanti"];


NSArray *arr1= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"USER"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
DLog(@"user Profile %@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:0]);
DLog(@"user Profile %@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:1]);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:1],[arr1 objectAtIndex:0]];




[newvCardTemp setJid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@localhost",str]]];
[newvCardTemp setFormattedName:@""];
[newvCardTemp setEmailAddresses:[getdic valueForKey:@"emailid"]];


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Profileimage"];

UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];
NSData *imageData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);

[newvCardTemp setPhoto:imageData1];
[xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
[xmppvCardTempModule activate:[self appDelegate].xmppStream];
[xmppvCardTempModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the user object from the XMPPUserCoreData, then use the user object to get the photo and name of user lists.

I use this code to fetch user. After user is fetched You can use `user.photo` to get user image, `user.displayName` to get user name, and section property of object of `NSFetchedResultsController`, to get status.
If section value is 0 then status : `Available`, if status is 1 : `Away`, else `Offline`

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerContacts
{
    if (fetchedUserLists == nil)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppDelegate delegate] managedObjectContext_roster];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:moc];

        NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, sd2, nil];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

        fetchedUserLists = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                           managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                             sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNum"
                                                                                      cacheName:nil];
        [fetchedUserLists setDelegate:(id)self];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![fetchedUserLists performFetch:&error])
        {
            DDLogError(@"Error performing fetch: %@", error);
        }
    }
    return fetchedUserLists;
}
```

For getting number of sections -> count

```
NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsControllerContacts] sections];
```

For getting number of rows in one section in `numberOfRowsInSection` method

```
if (section < [sections count])
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:sectionIndex];
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
}
```

For getting single user
Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsControllerContacts] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Hope it helps.
Happy coding ...

Comment: Thanks for your Quick Response.if (fetchedUserLists == nil) what is this,I didnt understand this statement.Where you get from it

Comment: That is a global variable of type "NSFetchedResultsController".  You can take your own

Comment: Added extra info displaying how to use the function, check the answer and let me know

Comment: Thanks for response.but i tried,i didn't get answer . i had 20 registred contacts im my contact list.I upload image and status of 20 contacts.Here my question is how can i get all 20 members profile pics and status

Comment: is there any delegate method can display all details